Proof that finitely generated modules have filtration from The Stacks Project
Context: Lemma 10.5.4 (00KZ) https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00KZ , states that a finitely generated module has a filtration,
$$0=M_0\subset M_1\subset....\subset M_{n-1}\subset M_n=M,$$
where $M_i$ are all finitely generated and for each $i\in\{1,....,n\}$, $M_{i}/M_{i-1}$ is isomorphic to $R/I_i$ for some ideal $I_i$ of $R$.
The proof starts by considering $\{x_1,...,x_r\}$ to be a generating set for $M$ and considers an induction argument on the number of generators. Its argued that $M'=R.x_1$ is isomorphic to $R/I_1$ where $I_1=\{f\in R| fx_1=0\}$. I understand that $M/M'$ has $r-1$ generators and that means we can do our induction argument. But, I have the following two questions,

Is it correct to take $M_n=M$, $M_{n-1}=M/M'$? If not, what is $M_{n-1}$?
How to show that indeed $M'$ is isomorphic as (what I think) $R$-module to $R/I_1$? I believe it is sufficient to specify where the single generator $x_1$ of $M'$ goes to in $R/I_1$ and extend $R$-linearly. But I am not sure what the image of $x_1$ should be.


Atiyah-MacDonald has some info on filtrations near the end of the book :)

Right now your post is not possible to understand without following the link. Bringing the full setup of the problem in to the post via an [edit] (for instance, what is $M'$?) will help your post, and it's a good habit to get in to for the future.

@KReiser made those changes now :)


No:  all the steps of the filtration should be submodules of $M$, not quotients.  Explicitly, if $M$ is generated by elements $x_1, \dots, x_r$, you can take $M_i$ to be the submodule generated by $x_1, \dots, x_i$.  So in particular we have $n=r$, and $M_{n-1}$ is the submodule generated by all but one of the given generators of $M$.

I would construct the map in the opposite direction.  There's a unique $R$-module homomorphism $R \to M'$ sending $1$ to $x_1$.  This is surjective by the definition of $M'$, and $I_1$ is (also by definition) its kernel.  Thus the first isomorphism theorem for $R$-modules gives us an isomorphism of $R$-modules $R/I_1 \to M'$.



Thanks @Ravi Fernando, will try to work through what you have said and will get back :)

(Perhaps this is wrong, but here is what I have) Take $M_r=M$. For $M_{r-1}$ generated by $x_1,...,x_{r-1}$ over $R$, note that the map $M_r\to M':=R.x_1$, $x=\sum_{i=1}^{r} a_ix_i\mapsto a_1x_1$ is a surjective $R$-linear map with kernel $M_{r-1}$. Using that $M'\cong R/I_1$, we have $M_r/M_{r-1}\cong R/I_1$. Now, we continue the same process for $M_{r-1}$ as our new $M$.

@frelg I think you may be misreading something:  the proof as stated in the Stacks project makes no direct use of $M_{r-1}$.  Rather, it constructs $M_1$ such that $M_1/M_0 = M_1/{0}$ is isomorphic to $R/I_1$, and then it applies the inductive hypothesis to the quotient $M/M_1$ (which is generated by the equivalence classes of $x_2, \dots, x_r$)--not the submodule $M_{r-1}$.

I get your point (will try to work on it), but is what I have fine too (for a proof of the statement, despite being different to what's on the Stacks project)?

Not quite:  your map $M = M_r \to M'$ isn't generally well-defined, because an element $x \in M$ may have multiple representations as $\sum a_i x_i$.  (This is a serious problem because unlike vector spaces, not every $R$-module has a basis.)  A second (minor and fixable) problem:  when the map is well-defined, its kernel is the submodule generated by $x_2, \dots, x_r$, which is slightly different from $M_{r-1}$ as we've defined it.
